# sort by days of the week after email line split

Tags: python

I have a code that retrieves [mbox.txt](http://www.py4inf.com/code/mbox.txt) and splits the `From` line to obtain days of the week and counts how often the day appears. I managed to do that but now I am stuck on how to sort the list according to the days of the week.

```
filename = input("Please Enter A File Name: ")
filehand = open (filename)
count=dict()
for line in filehand:
    if not line.startswith('From ') : continue 
    line = line.split() 
    day = line[2]  

    count[day] = count.get(day,0)+1

Flist = list()
for key, value in count.items():
    Flist.append((key, value))
Flist.sort(key = lambda l: (l[1], l[0]), )

for key, value in Flist:
     print (key, value)
```

My output:

```
Please Enter A File Name: mbox.txt
Sat 61
Sun 66
Wed 292
Mon 299
Fri 315
Tue 372
Thu 392
```

Is there a way I can get it to appear like the list below?

```
Mon 299
Tue 372
Wed 292
Thu 392
Fri 315
Sat 66
Sun 61
```

Comment: the key, value pairs in a python dictionary is by nature not ordered. Use an `ordereddict` if you want it ordered. More at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, use `collections.OrderedDict()`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

weekdays = OrderedDict({
    'Mon': 0,
    'Tue': 0,
    'Wed': 0,
    'Thu': 0,
    'Fri': 0,
    'Sat': 0,
    'Sun': 0})

filename = input("Please Enter A File Name: ")
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('From '): 
            line = line.strip().split() 
            weekdays[line[2]] += 1  

for weekday, count in weekdays.items():
    print(weekday, count)
```

Comment: Just as a side note, one Pythonic way of generating the zeroed dictionary is ```dict(zip(['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'], [0]*7))```.

Comment: Another side note, if you want to start your week on Sunday, you can just use ```weekdays.move_to_end('Sun', last=False)```.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this :

```
Flist.sort(key = lambda l: (l[1], l[0]), )
```

Try this :

```
days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

Flist = sorted(Flist, key= lambda l : days.index(l[0]))
# Or,
Flist.sort(key = lambda l: days.index(l[0]))
```